# Inputting x and y coordinates into table using geometry tokens via update cursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am brand new to Python and am having trouble with this objective in my Intro to Python for GIS assignment:

Independent step… Create two new fields in the attribute table named X and Y    (or something handy).   Populate that field with the X,Y location of the oilspill   points themselves!

Note: The oilspills featureclass has many points already with set geometry but the coordinates are not given in the existing table.

I have successfully created the new columns called X and Y using the following code:

```
import arcpy

oilspills = 'S:\\Lab 2\\oilspills.shp'

arcpy.AddField_management(oilspills, "X", "DOUBLE", "", "", "13", "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(oilspills, "Y", "DOUBLE", "", "", "13", "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
```

My issue now is that I can't figure out how to populate those new columns with the x and y coordinates for each point in the table. That said, I have managed to print out all the x and y coordinates for each point in the featureclass via the Python shell:

```
import arcpy

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('s:\\Lab 2\\oilspills.shp',['SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0]
        print row[1]
```

But I'm not sure how to combine the first part of my code and the second so the new columns I've created get populated with those values. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the new user [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 3):

You're very close - you just need to add your new fields into your cursor and set the value for `X` to be the value from `SHAPE@X`

```
import arcpy

oilspills = 'S:\\Lab 2\\oilspills.shp'

arcpy.AddField_management(oilspills, "X", "DOUBLE", "", "", "13", "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(oilspills, "Y", "DOUBLE", "", "", "13", "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(oilspills, ['SHAPE@X', 'SHAPE@Y', 'X', 'Y']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Populate X from Shape X
        row[2] = row[0]
        # Populate Y from Shape Y
        row[3] = row[1]
        # Save changes
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

To add a bit of explanation, your list of fields `['SHAPE@X', 'SHAPE@Y', 'X', 'Y']` are indexed in the row as `0, 1, 2, 3`, so the `SHAPE@X` is index `0` and `X` is index `2`.  So `row[2] = row[0]` means you are populating the `X` field with the value from the `SHAPE@X` field.